# my app working in apk but not working in aab

Tags: android, apk, android-app-bundle

I want to convert my project to android and publish it on play store. When I import it as apk, my project works fine, but when I import it as aab, my localization texts in the project are corrupted and the project does not work.Do I need to add it somewhere in the localization manager build settings? ( 0 Build Error)

I cant solution this problem

Answer (score 1):

Probable your resources splits for same builds of aab. Try turn off it in gradle file

```
bundle {
    language {
        enableSplit = false //android app bundle (aab) include all res languages
    }
}
```

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle/configure-base#version_and_updates

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. The enableSplit setting is already wrong in my project. I am also getting this problem in IOS build. I'm about to go crazy :/

Answer (score -2):

Check the Android SDK version and java JDK , try to update it .
good luck

Comment: first of all thanks for your answer. I update the jdk and sdk version but nothing changed

Comment: Trying to give a general answer to a question that lacks enough detail can always lead to answers that don't actually solve the problem, consider asking for more details through the question's comments and only post an answer when you're sure you actually have the solution.